# How to exit a tcl code after a proc has finished

Tags: tcl

I have a code as you can see below.
I execute this using hv (Altair hyperview) to load and take pictures of FE results.

This is the results log I see on my linux terminal:

```
*Ready
Loading Report...
Applying Report...
Ready
Ready
Capturing...
Ready*
```

It's stuck at "Ready" and unless I press Ctrl+c or enter it doesn't exit back to terminal. How can I make the code to exit to terminal after the proc is over?

So I just found out that the commands are running as a subprocess thats why I am not able to kill it with exit command.

```
proc BatchMain { } {
    set inputdeck [lindex $::argv 6]
    set resultfile [lindex $::argv 7]
    puts $inputdeck
    puts $resultfile

    set t [::post::GetT]
    hwi GetSessionHandle sess$t
    sess$t GetProjectHandle proj$t
    hwi OpenStack
    sess$t LoadReport Batch_Process.tpl
    sess$t ApplyReport Batch_Process replace true false 2 $inputdeck $resultfile

    set numpages [proj$t GetNumberOfPages];
    for {set i 1} {$i <= $numpages} {incr i} {
        proj$t SetActivePage $i
        proj$t GetPageHandle pg$t $i
        pg$t Draw
        pg$t ReleaseHandle
        sess$t CaptureScreen png image_$i.png
    }

    hwi CloseStack
    proj$t ReleaseHandle
    sess$t Close
}

BatchMain
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Bash?

Comment: `exit`? I have no idea what "hv" is.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way of stopping a Tcl program is to call the `exit` command. You could put this inside your `BatchMain`, or as its own call:

```
# ... procedure definition as in the question ...

BatchMain
exit
```

The `exit` command takes an optional exit code argument, with the usual definitions of what an exit code means, and where `0` is the default value. Under normal circumstances, `exit` has no Tcl result at all as it never finishes executing from the perspective of the script.

In some circumstances, Tcl will call `exit` for you. The most notable of these is when execution falls off the end of a classic `tclsh` script.

Comment: Programs can override `exit`, but if they do so and make `exit` not terminate the script, they're responsible for cleaning up the result!